# How can i write file ( pdf,txt,...) from NotesStream?

Tags: pdf, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a base64 encoded string. I want to decode it and burn out a file to pass on. I code this:

```
Function DecodeBase64(attachmentValue As String,attachmentName As String) As String
    Dim result As String
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim fileOut As String
    Dim fout As Integer
    Dim foutOpen As Integer
    Dim stream As NotesStream
    Dim dc As NotesDocumentCollection 

    'fout = Freefile

    fileOut = "C:\ExportFileLotus\" + attachmentName
    'Open fileOut For Output As fout
    'foutOpen = True
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set doc = db.CreateDocument

    s.ConvertMIME = False ' Do not convert MIME to rich text
    Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
    Set header = body.CreateHeader(attachmentName)
    Call header.SetHeaderVal("MIME document")
    Set stream = s.CreateStream
    Call stream.WriteText(attachmentValue,EOL_NONE)
    If stream.Bytes = 0 Then
        Messagebox fileInput,,"File has no content"
        Goto ExitSub
    End If
    'Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", ENC_BASE64)
    'Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "charset=UTF-8", ENC_BASE64)
    Call body.SetContentFromBytes(stream, "", ENC_BASE64)
    Call body.DecodeContent()
    stream.Open fileOut, "binary" 
    body.GetContentAsBytes stream, True 
    stream.Close 

    'Print #fout, body.ContentAsText
    'Close #fout
    DecodeBase64 = fileOut
ExitSub:
    s.ConvertMIME = True ' Restore conversion
End Function
```

Examples: attachmentValue = "VG9pIGxhIFF1aQ==" and attachmentName = "file.pdf".
When I write a txt file, it works fine. But I write a pdf file, it error and can not open.
How to fix it? Thanks for help!

Comment: Tôi tìm được ra lỗi của tôi là sai định dạng Call stream.WriteText(attachmentValue,EOL_CRLF).It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Set content type to `application/pdf` for pdf files:

```
Call body.SetContentFromText(stream, "application/pdf", ENC_BASE64)
```

Comment: How do i set content type to application/pdf for pdf?

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: It's still buggy. When I open the pdf file it informs: "Format error. Not a PDF or coruppted"

Comment: I find out my mistake is the wrong format when writeText Call stream.WriteText(attachmentValue,EOL_CRLF).It works fine!

Comment: Put your solution into an answer please and accept it later. This way people can find it easier when they face the same issue.

Comment: How can I write png file?

Comment: With Content type `image/png`. Look here for complete list: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I find out my mistake. `writeText` had the wrong format parameter.

```
Call stream.WriteText(attachmentValue, EOL_CRLF)
```

works fine.