# Lotusscript save base64 encoded string to file (DLL)

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

[EDIT] I believe i left out my original problem. To me it seems like the issue resides in passing the content of the decoded MIMEEntity to a stream, which i'd like to write out to a file. No matter how i attempt it, i can not get lotus script to write the binary data to the file. If anyone has any helpful opinion/suggestion/etc.., I'd be more then grateful!

[ORIGINAL]
I have the following code

```
Dim a As String
a = "TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" & _
"AAAAgAAAAA4fug4AtAnNIbgBTM0hVGhpcyBwcm9ncmFtIGNhbm5vdCBiZSBydW4gaW4gRE9TIG1v" & _
...
...

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim body As NotesMimeEntity
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set session = New NotesSession

 'Create stream and display properties
Set stream = session.CreateStream

 'check if the file exists
If Not stream.Open("C:\\Notes\\update.dll") Then
     'if the file doesnot exist then create one and add a time stamp to it
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    fileNum% = Freefile()
    Open "/ww414/notes/ebcdicfile.txt" For Output As fileNum%
    Close fileNum%
     'this should have created the file. see if it existis now
    If Not stream.Open("C:\\Notes\\update.dll") Then
   'if the file has not been created yet then let the user know of the error that blocks the operation
        Messagebox("Log file Is inaccessible")
    End If
End If

Dim b As NotesStream
Set b = session.CreateStream

Call b.WriteText(a)
'==========================================================


'update file with the b64 decoded content
Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doc = db.CreateDocument
session.ConvertMime = False

Set body = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
Call body.SetContentFromText(b, "", ENC_BASE64)
Call body.DecodeContent
content = body.ContentAsText
Call stream.WriteText(content)

'close stream/file open in memory
Call stream.Close()
```

The problem is, the file gets created, but when it comes to the content, it simply puts a few bytes in it (instead of the 14kb of actual file data)

I have checked a bunch of forums and possible solutions, but none of them seem to work.
For instance:
https://www.nsftools.com/tips/Base64v14.lss

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/e5f5333619f2996885256a220009508f/a8bb2c21c99f9c4d852571ee005cede9?OpenDocument

https://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/

Comment: Just a thought, does it work if you stream out to a file with a different extension (say .jpg or .gif)?  The hypothesis is that some antivirus process is blocking you from creating a .dll on the fly.

Comment: Hi! unfortunatel not :( I iterated through all the possible fileformats, also tried to setup the mime headers (so it'll recognize it as "application/octet-stream" and such) but without success. Also, i tried to copy what this guy did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796962/how-can-i-write-file-pdf-txt-from-notesstream but again, no success.

Comment: From the ContentAsText property help "Non-text data returns as-is which may present problems in further manipulation. For example, data containing a null character will probably be truncated at the null character during string manipulation"   It looks to me like you really want the .GetContentAsBytest() method instead.

Comment: I tried that as well, but for some reasons it did not work. However, i finally got it working! I'll write a detailed answer below in a moment. And huge thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution was even simpler as i thought.

[This](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_GETCONTENTASBYTES_METHOD_MIMEENTITY.html) was a huge help, as the root cause of my issue seemed to be the writing out the binary content to the disk. And that was due to creating the file the wrong way! While the file got created it couldn't output the content properly (for some "Lotus reasons"..)

Either way, taking a coffee break and starting everything from zero helped a lot! The code that worked (for future ref. if someone would need to get such a thing working):

```
Sub Initialize

Dim a As String
a ="BASE64 ENCODED STRING(In my case it was a DLL)" 

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim stream As NotesStream
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim body As NotesMimeEntity
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Set session = New NotesSession

Set stream = session.CreateStream

Dim b As NotesStream
Set b = session.CreateStream

Call b.WriteText(a, EOL_NONE)

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
Set doc = db.CreateDocument
session.ConvertMime = False

Set mime = doc.CreateMIMEEntity
Call mime.SetContentFromText(b, "application/octet-stream", ENC_BASE64)
Call mime.DecodeContent

If Not(mime Is Nothing) Then
    Set stream = session.CreateStream
    pathname$ = "c:\temp\test.dll"
    If Not stream.Open(pathname$, "binary") Then
        Messagebox pathname$,, "Open failed"
        Goto ExitSub
    End If
    Call mime.GetContentAsBytes(stream)
    Call stream.Close
Else
    Messagebox "Not MIME",, doc.GetItemValue("Subject")(0)
End If  
ExitSub:
    session.ConvertMIME = True ' Restore conversion
End Sub
```

Comment: Valid character sets include: ASCII, Big5, Binary, EUC-JP, EUC-KR, EUC-TW, GB2312, ISO-2022-JP, ISO-2022-KR, ISO-8859-1 through ISO-8859-9, ISO-8859-15, KOI8-R, Latin4, Shift_JIS, System, TCVN3, Unicode, Unicode-1-1, US-ASCII, UTF-7, UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, Windows-1250 through Windows-1258, and Windows-874. Binary implies byte operations only on the stream.   Default is "System" which apparently means "text."  All they're missing is Morse code.  Glad you got it working.